# Why key store not working after some day?

Tags: android, android-studio, keystore

I released my app signing it with a key. After some days when I was releasing it again with the same key, my device showed `app not installed` error. When I increased the app version, the app installed and I didn't get `app not installed` error but I could not install the app on the same version! I changed the key and after some days I'm having this problem again!
How to solve this problem? Why was my key destroyed?

Comment: try to install it with `adb`. What do you see?

Comment: And BTW why did you change the key if the problem was with the version?

Comment: for exam my app version is 1 when i release the app and install it, it installs well, but if i release again after some changes when i want to install it over installed app  with version 1, i get `App not installed` error

Comment: Which method are you using to install? Calling adb from Android Studio? Does this happen with any device? Did you try with an emulator? Are you building the debug version or the release? Try to add more info otherwise it's hard to help

Comment: i say that i release my app and get error. with debug version i haven't any problem. in device i get error and dos not test in emulator

Comment: I copy my released .apk file in my device and install it manually

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180572/discussion-between-kingston-and-mostafa3dmax).